# Ubuntu 16.04 Proxy settings

Tags: 16.04, server, proxy

We are using Ubuntu 16.04 (soon moving to 18.04/20.04). We use Icinga2 to monitor services and I have setup a proxy in /etc/environment:

```
export http_proxy="http://1.1.1.1:80"
export https_proxy="http://1.1.1.1:80"
export HTTP_PROXY="http://1.1.1.1:80"
export HTTPS_PROXY="http://1.1.1.1:80"
export ftp_proxy="http://1.1.1.1:80"
export no_proxy="2.2.2.2"
```

When I run a `wget` for example on terminal to 3.3.3.3 it pushes it to the proxy and if I do to 2.2.2.2 it goes direct. Perfect. However Icinga2 seems to completely ignore this and goes directly to 3.3.3.3 as well.

If I run it as the user Icinga2 uses (nagios) it goes via proxy to 3.3.3.3 and direct to 2.2.2.2.

Is there something I am missing? I have also tried to enter this in the `/etc/profile` to see if this has any effect. Tried a source `/etc/environment` and a reboot.

I have also sudo visudo and entered:

```
Defaults        env_keep = "http_proxy https_proxy no_proxy HTTP_PROXY HTTPS_PROXY NO_PROXY"
```

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Whether a software honours proxy depends on it’s developers. Seems that Icinga2 does not honour proxy.

Comment: You can try proxywise. https://launchpad.net/~anandogc/+archive/ubuntu/proxywise. It redirects all outgoing traffic through proxy.

Comment: Thanks you @turbulence, going to ask the question there too (just to make sure this isnt a bug or anything and my documentation becomes invalid...)

Comment: Yes it seems to be either a bug or a feature (as they seem to have decided to ignore proxy)